# React/JS - onMouseOver Changing the font

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseover

I am not familiar with code and languages or terminology but i wish to change `fontStyle1` from the scss to `fontStyle2` on Hover/mouseEnter in a decent way!

Thanks in advance.

scss:

```
fontStyle1{font-family: $Scope-One;}
fontStyle2{font-family: $Rouge-Script;}
```

js:

```
function NavBar() {
    return (
    <div>
    <Navbar className="colorNav" collapseOnSelect expand="lg" variant="dark">
    <Navbar.Brand id="fontStyle1" href="/">
      <img
        alt="BrandName"
        src= {Logo}
        width="30"
        height="30"
        className="d-inline-block align-top"
      />{' '}
      BrandName
    </Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav"/>
  <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
    <Nav className="mr-auto"/>
    <ul className="navbar-nav">
            <li><Link to={'/'} className="nav-link"> About </Link></li>
            <li><Link to={'/bookmark'} className="nav-link">Bookmark</Link></li>
    </ul>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
    </div>
    );
    }

    export default NavBar;
```

Comment: Your `fontstyle1` is an ID, I dont think its good to toggle ID, why dont you try class instead. Also could you please explain where you want to apply the mouse over event ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the hover style with SCSS:

```
.logo {
  font-family: $Scope-One;

  &:hover {
    font-family: $Rouge-Script;
  }
}
```

JS (have changed the id):

```
...
<Navbar.Brand id="navlogo" className="logo" href="/">
...
```

Comment: analogue9 appreciate your support it's working! Great Day

Comment: That's great! If you found the answer useful, please click the big tick to accept it.

Comment: am totally new to the world of code and so i dint know that. i did click the tick below 1; if am wrong please do correct me.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help.

Comment: if possible kindly answer [**link**] (_https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60050751/duplicating-component-in-react_) i want to create a repetitive component in react and to multiply using front-end.